# Google Apps Script - How to break loop to prevent error message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script for archiving rows from one sheet to another if some conditions are met (column G is not blank, and the date in column A is equal or older than 3 months). it appends the matching row to a new sheet and deletes the row from the original sheet.

```
function Archiving() {

  var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() || SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetID');
  var responseSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('responseSheetname');
  var archiveSheet = masterSS.getSheetByName('archiveSheetName');

  var responseData = responseSheet.getRange(2,1, responseSheet.getLastRow()-1, responseSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var lastRow = responseSheet.getLastRow();
  var today = new Date();
  for (var i = responseData.length-1; i < responseData.length; i--){
    var row = responseData[i];
    if (row[0] == "") {break;}
    if (row[6] != "") {
      var date = row[0];
      if (date != "" && ((today.getTime() - date.getTime()) > 7776000000)) {
        Logger.log(date)
        archiveSheet.appendRow(responseData[i]);
        responseSheet.deleteRow(i+2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's working, however, when it has completed archiving, it throws out the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 42, file "Archiving Script")

I figure this because it's still trying to loop through and finding nothing, something I had hoped the break would fix, but it hasn't.

Anyone able to suggest a fix?

Comment: Try `if (!row || row[0] == "") {break;}`

Comment: It seems that there is no end of the for loop of ``for (var i = responseData.length-1; i < responseData.length; i--){``. So how about modifying from ``i < responseData.length`` to ``i >= 0``?

Comment: Looks like @LGSon hit the nail on the head, that seems to have solved it. Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the fix was to change.

```
if (row[0] == "") {break;}
```

to

```
if (!row || row[0] == "") {break;}
```

Thanks for that LGSon.